# How to consume JRadioButton select on mouse click doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton, mouse-listeners, buttongroup

I'm creating a very simple class to override Swing JRadioButton which allows a user to set a field determining whether or not the radio button is selectable.

```
public class SelectableRadio extends JRadioButton implements MouseListener
private boolean selectable = true;
public SelectableRadio()
{
    super();
    addMouseListener(this);
}

public void setSelectable(boolean select)
{
    selectable = select;
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    if (!selectable)
    {
        e.consume();
    }
}
```

All of the other methods are implemented.  This does not work.  When a SelectableRadio button is set as NOT selectable, the radio button is still selected when clicked.

Any help?

Comment: why do you want to confuse your users?

Comment: If it's not selectable, just call `setSelection(false)` each time.

Comment: Or, to avoid confusing your users, as kleopatra said, disable the button directly.

Comment: I was simply trying to construct a Radio Button which did not Grey out and was not selectable in the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change your setSelectable code, and add the following:

```
if (editable) {
    this.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    super.enableEvents(Event.MOUSE_DOWN | Event.MOUSE_UP);
} else {
    this.setCursor(CursorFactory.createUnavailableCursor());
    super.disableEvents(Event.MOUSE_DOWN | Event.MOUSE_UP);
}
```

Comment: This is in fact what I was looking for.  Thanks for answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

You usually put `JRadioButton`s into a `ButtonGroup`.

Here's the example from the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html).

```
//Create the radio buttons.
JRadioButton birdButton = new JRadioButton(birdString);
birdButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
birdButton.setActionCommand(birdString);
birdButton.setSelected(true);

JRadioButton catButton = new JRadioButton(catString);
catButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
catButton.setActionCommand(catString);

JRadioButton dogButton = new JRadioButton(dogString);
dogButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
dogButton.setActionCommand(dogString);

JRadioButton rabbitButton = new JRadioButton(rabbitString);
rabbitButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
rabbitButton.setActionCommand(rabbitString);

JRadioButton pigButton = new JRadioButton(pigString);
pigButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_P);
pigButton.setActionCommand(pigString);

//Group the radio buttons.
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(birdButton);
group.add(catButton);
group.add(dogButton);
group.add(rabbitButton);
group.add(pigButton);

//Register a listener for the radio buttons.
birdButton.addActionListener(this);
catButton.addActionListener(this);
dogButton.addActionListener(this);
rabbitButton.addActionListener(this);
pigButton.addActionListener(this);
...
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    picture.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images/" 
                              + e.getActionCommand() 
                              + ".gif"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jRadioButton's enabled property? It makes it selectable or not-selectable.